# Why does my custom LWC not show in the builder of my Digital Experience

Tags: lightning-web-components, digital-experience, third-party

I have several custom LWC's I've designed - they all show up OK with no problem in my Digital Experience site -- except for one

When I go into the site builder to find the component, my palette displays this message:

> Some components in this section are blocked due to the site's security level setting

[image: screen shot from my builder UX]

I am developing a barcode scanning component that relies on a [3rd party script](https://docs.scandit.com/stable/web/), which I've referenced via static-resource - and because it also needs to reference yet other resources on a CDN, I have added the CDN's URL as a `Trusted Site` inside my Digital Experience's `Security & Privacy` settings

[image]

I've also ticked the `Show All Components` box in the `Advanced` settings panel

**UPDATE:**
I know from reading the 3rd party docs, the script library I'm referencing is experimentally supporting a custom Web Component - so I'm guessing it may be scouring the DOM for it's preferred little piece of markup - and other SF docs I've read seem to indicate that this is really frowned upon. That's my best guess as to why nothing I do works

**UPDATE:**
My `isExposed` element is already set to `true` - but thanks for the comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>SCANDIT Barcode Reader (Experimental)</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: i think lwc meta.xml file missing community targets or isExposed  true

Answer (score 0):

This might be very common, but make sure in your LWC's meta.xml file below pointer is in place:

```
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<Targets>
```

Many times due to this, components doesn't appear in community builder page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding capabilities to your LWC's meta.xml like below

```
<capabilities>
    <capability>lightningCommunity__RelaxedCSP</capability>
  </capabilities>
```

According to the explanation, it should fix your issue
[image]

Hope it helps.